# Angular Directive to round a decimal number

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Does Angular have a built-in directive to round the input value?

The number filter is not appropriate in this case because I want to round the actual `val` in ng-model as well.
If I have to write one, what would it be like?

Comment: The answer to your question is no. Angular does not have a built-in directive to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create two way binding conversion using directives. Here's a quick example:

```
app.directive('roundConverter', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      function roundNumber(val) {
        var parsed = parseFloat(val, 10);
        if(parsed !== parsed) { return null; } // check for NaN
        var rounded = Math.round(parsed);
        return rounded;
      }
      // Parsers take the view value and convert it to a model value.
      ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(roundNumber);
   }
 };
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/kz5QWIloxnd89RKtfkuE?p=preview

It really depends on how you want it to work. Should it restrict user input? Do you mind having the model and view value differ? Should invalid number inputs be null on the model? These are all decisions for you to make. The directive above will convert invalid numbers to null.

Comment: Is there a way to make the value in the input box update as well? It does bind to the ng-model, why is it not getting updates?

Comment: Yes you can, here's an updated plunk with that functionality. The reason I didn't initially include it is that you are no longer rounding numbers, simply restricting input of decimals. You can add more logic to suit the example to your needs.

http://plnkr.co/edit/BZHBJL4RZiStrcSTABZn?p=preview

Comment: @Adam that link on your comment, doesn't work, I can put decimals on the number.

Comment: Strange, I just tried and I can't. Not sure why it would be different for you.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `ngBlur` and `Math.round` in an expression:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="number" ng-blur="number = Math.round(number)" />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
      .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.val = 1234.56789;
}]);
</script>
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
<label>Enter number: <input ng-model='val'></label><br>
  Default formatting: <span id='number-default'>{{val | number}}</span><br>
  No fractions: <span>{{val | number:0}}</span><br>
  Negative number: <span>{{-val | number:4}}</span>
</div>
```

OUTPUT:
Enter number: 
1234.56789

Default formatting: 1,234.568

No fractions: 1,235

Negative number: -1,234.5679

Refrence : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number

Comment: Can you share some context to your answer?