# How can I round up a percentage with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I want to show the result of a test:

```
<span>{{test.correctCount / test.questions}}</span>%
```

But how can I show this as an integer number correctly rounded?

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326610/angular-directive-to-round-a-decimal-number

Comment: possible duplicate of [Math functions in angular bindings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740329/math-functions-in-angular-bindings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<span>{{(test.correctCount / test.questions)|number:0}}</span>%
```

Comment: do you mean one or two vertical bars ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number

You can do it like this:

```
 {{ number_expression | number : fractionSize}}
```

Also in this post there is an answer: [Math functions in angular bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740329/math-functions-in-angular-bindings) (post by Andrew Kuklewicz)

Answer (score 0):

```
<span>{{{{test.correctCount / test.questions}} | number:0}}</span>%
```

**Now its upto you ,How you want to show the result.**

- List item

Use **number:0** for (96%)

use **number:2** if you want to show like that (96.20%)